# Tableau - Find Highest Yearly Selling Product By Brand

Tags: tableau-api

I need to create a calculated field that returns the maximum yearly sales for each Brand of Products.

My worksheet is set up as:

```
[Brand], [Product], [Highest Sales LOD] to Rows

Sum([Sales]) to Text

[Product] to Color

YEAR([Year] to Filters
```

I currently have the following LOD ([Highest Sales LOD]):

```
 IF ([Sales])== ({FIXED [Brand]:MAX([Sales])}) THEN [Product] ELSE Null END
```

The LOD does return the values I need, until I apply the Year filter to the worksheet. It seems to be returning only the MAX Sales for each product, regardless of the Year.

This is a sample of my source data:

```
Year        Brand       Product     Units Sold
2000        Brand-X     Mayo            256
2000        Brand-X     Relish          498
2000        Brand-X     Jelly           62
2000        Brand-X     Mustard         581
2000        Brand-Y     Mayo            125
2000        Brand-Y     Jelly           29
2000        Brand-Z     Mayo            133
2000        Brand-Z     Relish          458
2000        Brand-Z     Jelly           521
2000        Brand-Z     Mustard         697
2000        Brand-Z     Salad Dressing      61
2001        Brand-X     Mayo            332
2001        Brand-X     Relish          409
2001        Brand-X     Jelly           64
2001        Brand-X     Mustard         435
2001        Brand-Y     Mayo            122
2001        Brand-Y     Jelly           26
2001        Brand-Z     Mayo            72
2001        Brand-Z     Relish          425
2001        Brand-Z     Jelly           432
2001        Brand-Z     Mustard         762
2001        Brand-Z     Salad Dressing      66
2002        Brand-X     Mayo            285
2002        Brand-X     Relish          556
2002        Brand-X     Jelly           30
2002        Brand-X     Mustard         614
2002        Brand-Y     Mayo            111
2002        Brand-Y     Jelly           37
2002        Brand-Z     Mayo            276
2002        Brand-Z     Relish          296
2002        Brand-Z     Jelly           378
2002        Brand-Z     Mustard         623
2002        Brand-Z     Salad Dressing      36
2003        Brand-X     Mayo            241
2003        Brand-X     Relish          480
2003        Brand-X     Jelly           92
2003        Brand-X     Mustard         653
2003        Brand-Y     Mayo            196
2003        Brand-Y     Jelly           108
2003        Brand-Z     Mayo            227
2003        Brand-Z     Relish          600
2003        Brand-Z     Jelly           571
2003        Brand-Z     Mustard         684
2003        Brand-Z     Salad Dressing      27
```

I would expect to see the LOD's output as:

```
Year             Brand           Product             Output
2000            Brand-X         Mustard         Mustard
2000            Brand-Y         Mayo            Mayo
2000            Brand-Z         Mustard         Mustard
2001            Brand-X         Mustard         Mustard
2001            Brand-Y         Mayo            Mayo
2001            Brand-Z         Mustard         Mustard
2002            Brand-X         Mustard         Mustard
2002            Brand-Y         Mayo            Mayo
2002            Brand-Z         Mustard         Mustard
2003            Brand-X         Mustard         Mustard
2003            Brand-Y         Mayo            Mayo
2003            Brand-Z         Mustard         Mustard
```

With all other Products set to Null.

Any and all suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome.

This occurs because the LOD calculation takes priority over the `YEAR` filter.

[image: Tableau kinds of filters]

To fix this, just click on the filter, and select option *Add to Context*.

Comment: That fixed the problem